# Adding a row after first row in a Table having only one row

Tags: vba, ms-word, rows

I need to add a row after first row in `MSWord Document`. Document have already one row and two columns containing `Country` in first cell and `Partner` in second cell as values of both cells. Problem with the following code is it only work with at-least two rows.

Macro should be able to add row and write predefined strings in both columns. This can be done in two ways

1. By adding a row at the end of the table and reaching to it and writing the strings.  If i do this then my question is how can I reach to the last row of the table?
2. By adding second row Everytime as mentioned in the following code.

   ```
   Set doc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\dell\Desktop\LATAM.DOCX", , , , , , , , , , , True)
   Set rng = doc.Content
   rng.Tables(1).Rows.Add (rng.Tables(1).Rows(2)) 'Here I am getting error 'required memeber of collect not exist.

   Set Cell = rng.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1)
   Set Cell2 = rng.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2)
   Cell.Range.Text = UT

   If UT = "CROATIA" Then Cell2.Range.Text = "ERSTE SECURITIES ZAGREB"
   If UT = "CZECH REPUBLIC" Then Cell2.Range.Text = "ERSTE GROUP"
   ```

Latam.docx look like this:

[image]

**Requirement**: After Macro it should be like this with values in added cells.

[image]

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```
Set doc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\ibnea\Desktop\List of Countries & Companies CEEMEA & LATAM.DOCX", , , , , , , , , , , True)
Set rng = doc.Content.Tables(1).Rows.Add
rng.Range.Font.Bold = False
rng.Cells(1).Range = UT
rng.Cells(2).Range = UT2
```

Comment: Leave teh parentheses and everything in them away (comment it out) and try again, with only `Rows.Add`

Comment: after adding row I need to write value in it how could it be done. for the first time `Doc` have only one row but after second time I run the macro `Document` will contain 2 row so on so forth. after your suggestion `Rows.Add` how could I write value to added row?

Comment: @CindyMeister I rephrase my Question please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't really understand your question but when I open a Word File and create a table with 1 row (as header) and 2 columns and enter "Country" and "Partner" then I can create a new row in this table with this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub addRow()
Dim tbl As Table

'set tble variable to Table with Index 1 in your document
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

'add a row to this table at the end
tbl.Rows.Add

'get last row in this table
Dim lastRow As Variant
lastRow = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows.Count

'write to the last row
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(lastRow, 1).Range = "your value in last row / column 1"
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(lastRow, 2).Range = "your value in last row / column 2"


End Sub
```

You said your list has only one row. This code now adds a row and fills in column 1 and 2 the value whatever is on the right side of the equality sign. It's still not clear what UT is and where it comes from. But anyway you can now access the last cells with this code.

Comment: if you remove this "(rng.Tables(1).Rows(2))" in the line where the error appear then it should work. "rng.Tables(1).Rows.Add" is enough

Comment: as I am working with ranges so its not `ActiveDocument`. one row as header and two columns having "Country" "Partner" is already written in Document.

Comment: 1 - > as I am working with ranges so its not `ActiveDocument`. 2- - > one row as header and two columns having "Country" "Partner" is already written in Document. 3 - - - > Is there a way to write string without making it bold???

Comment: @IbneAshiq Remember: on Stack Overflow one query per question. Please don't continue to extend your requirements in comments. Ask a new question for a new problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Rows.Add` without a parameter and the new row will be inserted at the end of the table. The parameter (as stated in the Help topic for `Rows.Add` enables code to insert new rows *before* a specific row.

In order to work with the new row, declare an object variable and assign the row to it when it's created. It's also a good idea to do this with the `Table` object. That way it's possible to address the objects directly, rather than needing to always use something like `rng.Tables(index).Rows(index)` not only is this simpler to read and write, it also executes more quickly.

So, based on the code in the question my recommendation:

```
Dim tbl as Word.Table, rw as Word.Row
Set tbl = rng.Tables(1)
Set rw = tbl.Rows.Add
rw.Cells(1).Range.Text = "cell content"
rw.Cells(2).Range.Text = "other cell content"
```